# I'm going through a django tutorial but currently stucked in an error i.e.. "Page Not Found" on admin page

Tags: python, django

> Page not found (404)

Request Method:

> GET

Request URL:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in just.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
1. admin/ 
2. shop/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have `DEBUG= True` in your Django settings file. Change that to `False`, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Here is my code:
Main ecom\urls.py:------------>>>>

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls'))
]
```

Now shop\urls.py:-------------->>>>

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index, name="ShopHome")
]
```

And shop\views.py:-------------->>>>

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Shop Index")
```

Please help me guys

Comment: You have no url matching the root of the site, you only have urls matching `/admin/...` and `/shop/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only pages that should be working for you right now is `/shop/` and `/admin/`. There is no root page because you have an include, which always start with `/shop/` and checks the `shop/urls`. Not sure what you want, but if you want the root page to give you the index view, you can change `ecom/urls` shop url to:

```
path('', views.index, name="ShopName)
```

Dont forget to import the views of course

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined blank URL. In main URLs.py, you have used `path('shop/', include('shop.urls'))`, and in shop urls.py `path("",views.index, name="ShopHome")`. this path will redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/` not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/.`

If you want blank url then do this: 
ecom\urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls'))
]
```

shop\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index, name="ShopHome")
]
```

remember whatever you add in `path('', include('shop.urls'))`, it will be added in all URLs written inside shop app.

If you want a blank URL and also "shop" added in rest of the URLs, do this:

```
From shop import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls'))
    path('',views.index, name="ShopHome")
]
```